# Where are the two recently confirmed unusual brown dwarfs?

Tags: distances, brown-dwarf

The News report of [two confirmed unusual T-type brown dwarfs](https://www.aninews.in/news/science/two-bizarre-brown-dwarfs-found-with-citizen-scientists-help20200711081438/) but they don't tell where in space or on the night sky they were found or how far they are from the Earth/Sun. The brown dwarfs are *WISE 0414* and *WISE 1810*. Does anyone know where they are located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant research paper is Schneider et al. (2020) "[WISEA J041451.67-585456.7 and WISEA J181006.18-101000.5: The First Extreme T-type Subdwarfs?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.03836)".

This gives the full designations, of which WISE 0414 and WISE 1810 are abbreviated forms. [The designations contain the J2000 coordinates](http://wise2.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/release/allwise/expsup/sec2_1a.html) (J041451.67-585456.7 refers to right ascension 04<sup>h</sup>14<sup>m</sup>51.67<sup>s</sup>, declination -58°54′56.7″). It turns out that WISE 0414 is in Reticulum and WISE 1810 is in Serpens (Cauda).

The distances are highly uncertain, from the paper:

> If we proceed with absolute magnitude–spectral type relations for field brown
> dwarfs (Dupuy, & Liu 2012) and designate the spectral
> type of WISEA 1810−1010 to be T0, wildly discrepant
> distances are found for different passbands. **We find a
> distance of ∼14 pc using WISEA 1810−1010’s W2 magnitude, but a distance of ∼67 pc using the K−band
> magnitude.** Combined with our measured proper motion (Table 1), these distance estimates lead to a $V_\mathrm{tan}$
> range of 77–360 km s<sup>−1</sup>. **For WISEA 0414−5854, a similarly large distance range is found (52–94 pc),** corresponding to a $V_\mathrm{tan}$ range of 170–307 km s<sup>−1</sup>. Parallax
> measurements for these objects will be necessary to determine accurate $V_\mathrm{tan}$ values. Nevertheless, it is clear
> that both sources are high velocity objects consistent
> with membership in the metal-poor Galactic thick disk
> or halo.

(emphasis mine)